# Using expanduser lead to typeerror : str or object but not integer

Tags: python, string, parsing, integer, arguments

I am defining different types of argument to use with command line in order to run a script on a temrinal.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--indir1', type=str, required=True, help='Path to raw data directory.')
parser.add_argument('--indir2', type=str, required=True, help='Path to raw data directory.')
parser.add_argument('--outdir', type=str, required=True, help='Path to accuracy file directory.')
parser.add_argument('--testdir', type=str, required=True, help='Path to test file directory.')
parser.add_argument('--language_model_dir', type=str, required=True, help='path to language model directory.')
parser.add_argument('--r', type=int, default=90, help='ratio for training between 70, 80, 90 ')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I am getting the following error when trying to use the "r" argument which is supposed to be an integer

```
def splitting(dataset_data, dataset_label, ratio):

    if ratio == 90:
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset_data, dataset_label, test_size=0.10, random_state=42, stratify=dataset_label)  # get same proportion and reproductible
    elif ratio ==80:
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset_data, dataset_label, test_size=0.20, random_state=42,
    stratify = dataset_label)  # get same proportion and reproductible
    elif ratio ==70:
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset_data, dataset_label, test_size=0.30, random_state=42,
    stratify = dataset_label)  # get same proportion and reproductible
    else:
        raise ValueError('Values accepted 70 , 80 , 90')

    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test

def main():

    indir1 = os.path.expanduser(args.indir1)
    testdir = os.path.expanduser(args.testdir)
    r = os.path.expanduser(args.r)

    # Getting train result with cross validation for original data
    list_train, l,  list_test, l_2, name = splitting(tr, l , r)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cross_val_original.py", line 199, in <module>
    main()
  File "cross_val_original.py", line 189, in main
    r = os.path.expanduser(args.r)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 235, in expanduser
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

Comment: You are passing an `int` object where as `expanduser` expects `str, bytes or os.PathLike object` type as an argument.

Comment: So how can If i comment out the line with ratio and expansue I get "ratio_training is not define " How can I use agument with int value

Comment: Do you understand what expanduser *does*? Why are you calling it on an integer? That makes no sense. Please read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).